# Console.ReadLine() не срабатывает

Tags: c#

написал первую програму на С шарп.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Reflection;

[assembly: AssemblyVersionAttribute("1")]
namespace SimplecSharpApp
{
    class Prorgam
    {
        static int Main(string[]args)
        {
            for (int i=0; i<args.Length; i++)
                Console.WriteLine("Arg: {0}", args[1]);
            Console.ReadLine();
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

В среде MSVStudio в режиме отладки запускается и завершается нормально, но 
Console.ReadLine() не срабатывает, программа не останавливается и возможности ввести данные нет.

В чем дело не пойму. Прошу прокомментировать ситуацию.

Comment: `возможности ввести данные нет.` - в данной ситуации интересен вопрос: ввести данные куда? я не про саму консоль.............а так - скорее всего нужно `Console.ReadLine()` в тело цикла поместить

Comment: @АлексейШиманский в цикле аргументы командной строки выводятся. зачем там ввод какой то? :) видимо речь и том, чтобы подтверждающий enter нажать.

Comment: вы там что за аргументы то передаете? стандартный ввод случаем не переопределяете?

Comment: @teran так может там типа надо задать имя возраст... откуда ж я знаю

Comment: Странно. Я попробовал ваш код, у меня останавливается.

Comment: Это первая програма из учебника. Особого смысла в ней искать не стоит. 1. данные внести (ввести) из стандартного потока.2. Да. Забыл написать, что Console.WriteLine("Arg: {0}", args[1]) не выводит на экран ничего.

Comment: Подозреваю, что со стандартным вводом что-то. Но ни каких действий с ним не выполнял.

Comment: `[assembly: AssemblyVersionAttribute("1")]` - а это зачем? И метод `Main()` не должен ничего возвращать, т.е. быть `void`.

Comment: Все. Победил. Создавал проект как "Пустое универсальное приложение", а нужно было как "Консольное". Теперь интересно чем они отличаются.

Comment: 1. AssemblyVersionAttribute("1") ввел, потому, что было замечание, не ошибка. Посмотрел как устраняется. 2. Сначала main возвращал void. Потом в учебнике был раздел про возвращаемые значения. Изменил.

Comment: @УсковАндрей: Ох. В «универсальных» приложениях консоли, кажется, просто нет. Напишите ответ, будет полезно для других читателей.

Comment: Да. На самом деле нужно просто выбрать консольное приложение.

Answer (score 1):

Консоли в UWP действительно нет.
Если сильно нужно что-то вывести в окно вывода во время отладки программы, то можно использовать `Debug.Writeline(..)`. При запуске отладки вашего приложения эти сообщения будут отображаться в окне вывода (стандартный ярлык VS - Ctrl + Alt + O, ReSharper ярлык Ctrl + W, O)